# lxml can parse part of tr in python

Tags: python, lxml

when i use lmxl to parse a web ,the lxml-xpath can get part of  target,please see my code:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
url="http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm" 
file=urllib.urlopen(url).read() 
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
for company in root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal"]'):
    print  company.text_content().encode('utf-8')  

>>>00325创生控股1,000#     
00326中国星集团50,000#     
00327百富环球1,000  
00328ALCO HOLDINGS2,000#     
00329  
>>>
```

there are two problems:
1.why i get can only 000329?the other matrial lost?
2.why i can't get the company infomation whose code is bigger than  000329?

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us the link to the page you are trying to parse? I can hardly read in the screenshot... And seeing the source html might also be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps the `.read()` was incomplete; try `lxml.html.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))` instead (note, no `.read()` call, leave that to the parser).

Comment: url="http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"

Answer (score 1):

`read()` does not read the complete page at once. you need to iterate on it

From the documentation:

> the read() method, if the size argument is omitted or negative, may not read until the end of the data stream; there is no good way to determine that the entire stream from a socket has been read in the general case.

Comment: i have tried  with  lxml.html.parse(urllib.urlopen(url)),it's no use,maybe it is a problem of encoding